# How to make pandas list without brackets between cells in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list which I get from reading gsheet, it has all values in square brackets like this:

```
[['example1'], ['example2'], ['example3'], ['example4'], ['example5']]
```

I would like to remove brackets from values for further steps and it should look like:

```
['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5']
```

I'm stuck here for a while, any help is appreciated.
Bit of my code:

```
    SOURCE_SHEET = CLIENT.open_by_url(SOURCE_G_SHEET_URL).worksheet(source_ws_title)
    rows_read = SOURCE_SHEET.get_all_records()
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame(rows_read)
    list = df_raw.values.tolist()
```

Comment: As side note: avoid using `list` as variable name, as this overshadow `list` built-in

Comment: As another side note: I assume you want to load a worksheet from Google Sheets to a Pandas Dataframe. I really like this function of Pygsheets which does exactly that: https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_as_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to extract every element from the inner list and put it in the main list, something like this:

```
[j for i in init_list for j in i]
```

How does it work? Think of it as a for look:

```
final_list = []
for i in init_list:
    for j in i:
        final_list.append(j)
```

Another way to do is using `numpy`'s `squeeze` function.

```
x = np.array(init_list)
np.squeeze(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If every list in the list has only one record, you can do this list comprehension as well:

```
[i[0] for i in initial_list]
```